# Programmatically insert and remove kernel modules in C

Tags: c, linux, kernel, module

Is there anyway to do "insmod" and "rmmod" from C/C++ code?  Other than running system(...), is there a Kernel API that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Look in the source code of insmod?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at the [module-init-tools](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/module-init-tools/module-init-tools-latest.tar.gz) source?

Comment: Excellent thanks for that, that should help me.  I forgot that I can just look at the source for almost anything.. still stuck in Windows world mentally.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to viewing the source for `insmod` and *module-init-tools* you could `strace` and `ltrace` a run of `insmod`.